# Are additional settings required for AngularJS routing to work in asp.net Web Application (Not MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, routes, route-provider

Having problems getting angularJS **routing** to work in my asp.net application.

Note: AngularJS routing basically allows multiple views to be inserted interchangeably into the same page without page refresh.

Are their any connection settings or http settings that need to be adjusted in order for routing to work? Can AngularJS routing work with the ASP settings "right out of the box" (after of course including the angular.min.js/angular-route.js scripts)?

Just implementing a plain ASP.NET Web Application

[image]

[image]

I found a few tutorials on the web like this one, however they don't help with routing, and sometimes use templates that are not available.

https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/angularjs-for-asp-net-applications

**For Clarification**
This post is asking if any additional settings are required, or if routing works right out of the box with an ASP Web Application as long as the required angular scripts(angular.min.js/angular-route.js) are included.

**Angular Example**
--Index.aspx--

```
<div ng-app="AngularStore" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="min-height:400px;">  
    <div ng-controller="mainController"> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#/cart">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/store">Store</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="main">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<%--//javascript scripts--%>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

--script.js--

```
var storeApp = angular.module('AngularStore', ['ngRoute']).

config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/store', {
      templateUrl: "partials/store.html",
      controller: 'HomeController'
  }).
  when('/products/:productSku', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/product.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
  }).
  when('/cart', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/shoppingCart.html',
      controller: 'cartController'
  }).
  otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/cart'
  });
}]);

//I have tried including $route in function dependencies here.
storeApp.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
// create a message to display in our view
$scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

storeApp.controller('cartController', function ($scope) {
$scope.message = 'Look! I am a cartController page.';
});

storeApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
$scope.message = 'Look! I am a mainController page.';
});
```

[image]

Comment: "Having problems getting angularJS routing to work in my asp.net application." -- Are you able to provide any more info than this?  Error messages, Unexpected behavior, etc...

Comment: I am asking if any additional settings are required, or if routing works right out of the box with an ASP Web Application. I will adjust the question for clarity.

Comment: One of the things that probably won't work right out of the box is the need to configure your web server so that it's aware of your single page application. Let say your app is served from the root of the web site `/`. If a user navigates to a route inside your app, say `/home` Angular takes care of it shows the right view.  Now if the user refreshes the page (while on the `/home` url), the web server needs to know that it should serve the files for the single page app, and not look for a directory named "home" on the server. I use nginx, however, and can't say much more about ASP.

Comment: So if i choose ASP.NET Single Page application, it has a bunch of htmlcs pages. I cant use HTML pages. Not sure how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These additional steps made it work.

1. Add #/ before the hrefs:

   ```
   <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
   ```
2. Add this locationProvider config before your routeProvider.

   ```
   scotchApp.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
       $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
   }]);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this before with minimal issues.  Cant recall any special settings that needed to be set.  Form validation can be tricky as the web application wraps most of the page in a form.  Without more information on your specific problems that is all I am able to provide.

Comment: hi Shane, I added my code. I was convinced after trying so many different tutorials that it was an ASP.NET thing

Comment: Adding your code does not help in this case.. We need a better description of the problem.  Error messages, Description of Unexpected behavior, etc...  Also is there a specific reason you want to mix these two technologies?  If you are using angular why not set up a Web API back end?

Comment: And just make the client-side pages with HTML, what Visual Studio template do you use for this?

Comment: If you just have any advice on how to set up the client side. I know how to make an asp.net web api.

Comment: If the angular front end and the Web API back end are intended to be "together" I would generally create a solution with 2 projects, one for the Angular front end and one for the Web API back end.  Create a folder for your client side HTML and Javascript, then right-click your solution in Visual Studio, go to Add and choose exisiting website.  Here is an example from one of my repositories.. it could be laid out a little cleaner, but should give you an idea. https://github.com/shaneray/ShaneSpace.GameSite

Comment: How did you make the front end project? did you just create some folders on you desktop? Like what selection did you make when you clicked new project?

Comment: You don't use new project... see my comment above regarding right clicking on the solution and add existing website

Comment: how did you make the "existing website"? Anyways, I appreciate your feedback. I'm sure i'll figure it out.

Comment: Create a folder for your client side HTML and JavaScript.  Then choose that folder as the existing website